Reduce Redundant Code For Optimization of Border Cubes in Unity C# Project
I just created my account on StackOverflow and first time putting here a question so I apologize if I write something inefficiently. I will try to describe my problem the most efficiently I can, however if you are missing any extra information, please tell it and I will provide it.
I'm issuing with optimization script for my learning project where I'm trying to create base functionality of Minecraft.
I've created two methods for border cubes in chunks which are ensuring that border cubes that are covered from each directions with other cubes wont instantiate or if they are already instantiated then they will be deactivated.

❓ The problem is that these two methods contain redundant code which I want to get rid off to make this script cleaner.

Following method is ensuring that if New Cube in New Chunk is surrounded from each sides, then it takes certain parameter which won't let this cube Instantiate in the future.
private void BorderCubesOptimizationsOfNewChunk(CubeData newCubeData, Dictionary<Vector3, CubeData> newChunkFieldData, Vector3 centerOfNeigbourChunk, Vector3 neighbourCubePosition, Border border, Corner corner)
    {
        Dictionary<Vector3, CubeParameters> neighbourChunk = mapGenerator.dictionaryOfCentersWithItsChunkField[centerOfNeigbourChunk];

        // WIP
        if (corner != Corner.Null)
        {
            if (corner == Corner.XNegative_ZNegative)
            {

            }
            else if (corner == Corner.XNegative_ZPositive)
            {

            }
            else if (corner == Corner.XPositive_ZNegative)
            {

            }
            else if (corner == Corner.XPositive_ZPositive)
            {

            }
            return;
        }

        // If there is a Cube in New Chunk bellow New Cube, then return
        if (!newChunkFieldData.ContainsKey(newCubeData.position - Vector3.up))
        {
            return;
        }
        // If there is a Cube in New Chunk above New Cube, then return
        if (!newChunkFieldData.ContainsKey(newCubeData.position + Vector3.up))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (border != Border.XNegative)
        {
            // If there is a Cube in New Chunk at decremented X position, then return
            if (!newChunkFieldData.ContainsKey(newCubeData.position - Vector3.right))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If there is a Cube in Neighbour Chunk at decremented X position, then return
            if (!neighbourChunk.ContainsKey(neighbourCubePosition))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        if (border != Border.XPositive)
        {
            // If there is a Cube in New Chunk at incremented X position, then return
            if (!newChunkFieldData.ContainsKey(newCubeData.position + Vector3.right))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If there is a Cube in Neighbour Chunk at incremented X position, then return
            if (!neighbourChunk.ContainsKey(neighbourCubePosition))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        if (border != Border.ZNegative)
        {
            // If there is a Cube in New Chunk at decremented Z position, then return
            if (!newChunkFieldData.ContainsKey(newCubeData.position - Vector3.forward))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If there is a Cube in Neighbour Chunk at decremented Z position, then return
            if (!neighbourChunk.ContainsKey(neighbourCubePosition))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        if (border != Border.ZPositive)
        {
            // If there is a Cube in New Chunk at incremented Z position, then return
            if (!newChunkFieldData.ContainsKey(newCubeData.position + Vector3.forward))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If there is a Cube in Neighbout Chunk at incremented Z position, then return
            if (!neighbourChunk.ContainsKey(neighbourCubePosition))
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        newCubeData.isCubeDataSurrounded = true;
    }

Then I have very similar method which is ensuring that if Neighbor Cube in Neighbor Chunk is surrounded from each sides, then it deactivate that cube. But it isn't the only thing that differs, to make it working I had to reverse operators for border conditions.
private void BorderCubesOptimizationsOfNeighbourChunk(Dictionary<Vector3, CubeData> newChunkFieldData, CubeData newCubeData, Vector3 centerOfNeigbourChunk, Vector3 neighbourCubePosition, Border border, Corner corner)
    {
        Dictionary<Vector3, CubeParameters> neighbourChunk = mapGenerator.dictionaryOfCentersWithItsChunkField[centerOfNeigbourChunk];

        // WIP
        if (corner != Corner.Null)
        {
            if (true)
            {

            }
            else if (true)
            {

            }
            else if (true)
            {

            }
            else if (true)
            {

            }
            return;
        }

        // If there is a Cube in Neighbour Chunk bellow Neighbour Cube, then return
        if (!neighbourChunk.ContainsKey(neighbourCubePosition - Vector3.up))
        {
            return;
        }
        // If there is a Cube in Neighbour Chunk bellow Neighbour Cube, then return
        if (!neighbourChunk.ContainsKey(neighbourCubePosition + Vector3.up))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (border != Border.XNegative)
        {
            // If there is Cube in Neighbour Chunk at incremented X position, then return
            if (!neighbourChunk.ContainsKey(neighbourCubePosition + Vector3.right))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If there is Cube in New Chunk at incremented X position, then return
            if (!newChunkFieldData.ContainsKey(newCubeData.position))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        if (border != Border.XPositive)
        {
            // If there is Cube in Neighbour Chunk at decremented X position, then return
            if (!neighbourChunk.ContainsKey(neighbourCubePosition - Vector3.right))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If there is Cube in New Chunk at decremented X position, then return
            if (!newChunkFieldData.ContainsKey(newCubeData.position))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        if (border != Border.ZNegative)
        {
            // If there is Cube in Neighbour Chunk at incremented Z position, then return
            if (!neighbourChunk.ContainsKey(neighbourCubePosition + Vector3.forward))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If there is Cube in New Chunk at incremented Z position, then return
            if (!newChunkFieldData.ContainsKey(newCubeData.position))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        if (border != Border.ZPositive)
        {
            // If there is cube in Neighbour Chunk at decremented Z position, then return
            if (!neighbourChunk.ContainsKey(neighbourCubePosition - Vector3.forward))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If there is cube in New Chunk at decremented Z position, then return
            if (!newChunkFieldData.ContainsKey(newCubeData.position))
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        neighbourChunk[neighbourCubePosition].cubeInstance.gameObject.SetActive(false);

And there I'm rather providing a method that use both of methods I provided above. This method can be optimized too to get rid of redundant code, but I will be working on it in the future.
private void OptimizeDataOfNewChunk(CubeData newCubeData, Vector3 centerOfUpcomingChunk, Dictionary<Vector3, CubeData> newChunkFieldData)
    {
        Border border = Border.Null;
        Corner corner = Corner.Null;

        // Negative X border of actual chunk
        // If actual cube postion is on border of actual chunk and if border chunk exist, optimalize borders of these two chunks
        if ((newCubeData.position.x - (mapGenerator.gridSize.x / 2)) % mapGenerator.gridSize.x == 0)
        {
            if (mapGenerator.dictionaryOfCentersWithItsChunkField.ContainsKey(centerOfXPositiveNeighbourChunk))
            {
                border = Border.XPositive;
                // WIP: X positive - Z positive corner
                if (newCubeData.position.z == centerOfUpcomingChunk.z + Mathf.Ceil((float)mapGenerator.gridSize.x / 2.0f) - 1.0f)
                {

                }

                // WIP: X positive - Z negative corner
                else if (newCubeData.position.z == centerOfUpcomingChunk.z - Mathf.Ceil((float)mapGenerator.gridSize.x / 2.0f) + 1.0f)
                {

                }

                BorderCubesOptimizationsOfNewChunk(newCubeData, newChunkFieldData, centerOfXPositiveNeighbourChunk, newCubeData.position + Vector3.right, border, Corner.Null);
                BorderCubesOptimizationsOfNeighbourChunk(newChunkFieldData, newCubeData, centerOfXPositiveNeighbourChunk, newCubeData.position + Vector3.right, border, Corner.Null);
                return;
            }
        }
        // Positive X border of actual chunk
        // If actual cube postion is on border of actual chunk and if border chunk exist, optimalize borders of these two chunks
        else if ((newCubeData.position.x + (mapGenerator.gridSize.x / 2)) % mapGenerator.gridSize.x == 0)
        {
            if (mapGenerator.dictionaryOfCentersWithItsChunkField.ContainsKey(centerOfXNegativeNeighbourChunk))
            {
                border = Border.XNegative;
                // WIP: X negative - Z positive corner
                if (newCubeData.position.z == centerOfUpcomingChunk.z + Mathf.Ceil((float)mapGenerator.gridSize.z / 2.0f) - 1.0f)
                {

                }

                // WIP: X negative - Z negative corner
                else if (newCubeData.position.z == centerOfUpcomingChunk.z - Mathf.Ceil((float)mapGenerator.gridSize.z / 2.0f) + 1.0f)
                {

                }

                BorderCubesOptimizationsOfNewChunk(newCubeData, newChunkFieldData, centerOfXNegativeNeighbourChunk, newCubeData.position + Vector3.left, border, Corner.Null);
                BorderCubesOptimizationsOfNeighbourChunk(newChunkFieldData, newCubeData, centerOfXNegativeNeighbourChunk, newCubeData.position + Vector3.left, border, Corner.Null);
                return;
            }
        }
        // Negative Z border of actual chunk
        // If actual cube postion is on border of actual chunk and if border chunk exist, optimalize borders of these two chunks
        else if ((newCubeData.position.z - (mapGenerator.gridSize.x / 2)) % mapGenerator.gridSize.x == 0)
        {
            if (mapGenerator.dictionaryOfCentersWithItsChunkField.ContainsKey(centerOfZPositiveNeighbourChunk))
            {
                border = Border.ZPositive;
                // Z positive - X positive corner
                if (newCubeData.position.x == centerOfUpcomingChunk.x + Mathf.Ceil((float)mapGenerator.gridSize.x / 2.0f) - 1.0f)
                {

                }

                // Z negative - X negative corner
                else if (newCubeData.position.x == centerOfUpcomingChunk.x - Mathf.Ceil((float)mapGenerator.gridSize.x / 2.0f) + 1.0f)
                {

                }

                BorderCubesOptimizationsOfNewChunk(newCubeData, newChunkFieldData, centerOfZPositiveNeighbourChunk, newCubeData.position + Vector3.forward, border, Corner.Null);
                BorderCubesOptimizationsOfNeighbourChunk(newChunkFieldData, newCubeData, centerOfZPositiveNeighbourChunk, newCubeData.position + Vector3.forward, border, Corner.Null);
                return;
            }
        }
        // Postive Z border of actual chunk
        // If actual cube postion is on border of actual chunk and if border chunk exist, optimalize borders of these two chunks
        else if ((newCubeData.position.z + (mapGenerator.gridSize.x / 2)) % mapGenerator.gridSize.x == 0)
        {
            if (mapGenerator.dictionaryOfCentersWithItsChunkField.ContainsKey(centerOfZNegativeNeighbourChunk))
            {
                border = Border.ZNegative;
                // Z negative - X positive corner
                if (newCubeData.position.x == centerOfUpcomingChunk.x + Mathf.Ceil((float)mapGenerator.gridSize.x / 2.0f) - 1.0f)
                {

                }

                // Z negative - X negative corner
                else if (newCubeData.position.x == centerOfUpcomingChunk.x - Mathf.Ceil((float)mapGenerator.gridSize.x / 2.0f) + 1.0f)
                {

                }

                BorderCubesOptimizationsOfNewChunk(newCubeData, newChunkFieldData, centerOfZNegativeNeighbourChunk, newCubeData.position + Vector3.back, border, Corner.Null);
                BorderCubesOptimizationsOfNeighbourChunk(newChunkFieldData, newCubeData, centerOfZNegativeNeighbourChunk, newCubeData.position + Vector3.back, border, Corner.Null);
                return;
            }
        }

        DeactiavateSurroundedCubeData(newCubeData, newChunkFieldData);
    }

I think it's possible to put each conditions from BorderCubesOptimizationsOfNewChunk and BorderCubesOptimizationsOfNeighbourChunk methods to one method using generics.
I know what is generics and quietly know how to use it on very low level, but I haven't used it in more complex code before. I've tried to find some documentation and videos to learn how to use generics, but it haven't helped me even to be sure that I'm on the right way.
Also I asked ChatGPT to split these two methods to one method using generics and any of its responses didn't make me a bit closer to resolve this puzzle. I've tried one implementation it provided me, but it gave me out of the line response which makes OptimizeDataOfNewChunk method generics, but didn't even use it.
However, even if I try to use generics to generalize dictionaries I'm using as chunks, then I don't know how to ensure that for Neighbor Cubes or New Cubes, there will be appreciate operators with corresponding conditions.
I will be very thankful for design advice or links to studying material which will provide me efficient way to resolve it. 

I've tried to investigate responses which ChatGPT gave me and I think I found satisfying response. I will try to split these two methods into three methods like it does, but without looking on the code it provided me.
https://chatgpt.com/share/66e84a68-68c8-800d-ba6f-bfba22105a13
However I'm still not sure if it will save me, and I'm open to any other suggestions.

Your if checks for the directions you could just use an array of directions like private static readonky Vector3[] directions = new[]{ Vector3.up, Vector3.down, Vector3.right, Vector3.left }; and use a loop instead..

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Thank you very much for the answer Hugo! I feel a bit ashamed that I didn't find it by myself and created that monster frankenstein if else bunch of code :D. However I use that field you provided me to check each direction and find how to use generics, so now I created really compact code. Thanks once more!

Please post the corrected code as an answer, instead of an edit to the question. (So other people know that this has been solved)

The topic is resolved. I put my new code bellow. I've created 2 arrays that are representing each existing borders and positions for cubes and put it into foreach loops where I'm checking cubes from each sides according to border. Also I found how to use generics and used it to put it into one method (IsBorderCubeSurrounded) instead of having two methods for new chunk and for neighbor chunk.
private void BorderCubeOptimizationSequence(Dictionary<Vector3, CubeData> newChunkFieldData, CubeData newCubeData, Border newChunkBorder, Dictionary<Vector3, CubeParameters> neighbourChunkField, Vector3 neighbourCubePosition, Border neighbourChynkBorder)
    {
        // Return if New Cube in New Chunk isn't surrounded with cubes from each sides
        if (!IsBorderCubeSurrounded<CubeData, CubeParameters>(newChunkFieldData, newCubeData.position, neighbourChunkField, neighbourCubePosition, newChunkBorder))
        {
            return;
        }
        newCubeData.isCubeDataSurrounded = true;

        // Return if Neighbor Cube in Neighbor Chunk isn't surrounded with cubes from each sides
        if (!IsBorderCubeSurrounded<CubeParameters, CubeData>(neighbourChunkField, neighbourCubePosition, newChunkFieldData, newCubeData.position, neighbourChynkBorder))
        {
            return;
        }
        neighbourChunkField[neighbourCubePosition].cubeInstance.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private bool IsBorderCubeSurrounded<T, A>(Dictionary<Vector3, T> firstChunkFieldData, Vector3 firstCubePosition, Dictionary<Vector3, A> secondChunkFieldData, Vector3 secondCubePosition, Border border)
    {
        foreach (Border actaualBorder in borders)
        {
            foreach (Vector3 actualDirection in directions)
            {
                // Continue to the next foreach interation if Actual Direction is the same as Current Border
                if (isDirectionSameAsBorder(actualDirection, border))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (actaualBorder != border)
                {
                    if (!firstChunkFieldData.ContainsKey(firstCubePosition + actualDirection))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!secondChunkFieldData.ContainsKey(secondCubePosition))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private bool isDirectionSameAsBorder(Vector3 actualDirection, Border border)
    {
        if (actualDirection == Vector3.right && border == Border.XPositive)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (actualDirection == -(Vector3.right) && border == Border.XNegative)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (actualDirection == Vector3.forward && border == Border.ZPositive)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (actualDirection == -(Vector3.forward) && border == Border.ZNegative)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

